# AWS load balancer connection draining in combination with server-sent events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, server-sent-events, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using [Server-Sent Events](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events) (SSE) in a Node.js service that runs in AWS Elastic Beanstalk behind a Classic Load Balancer. In the load balancer, we have enabled connection draining with a timeout of 15 minutes, so that when an instance goes out-of-service, long-running in-flight requests have a chance to finish. However, as any SSE connection will also be seen as an in-flight request, and will not automatically finish due to the nature of SSE, this means that an instance will always take the full 15 minutes to go out-of-service.

To solve this problem, so far we have considered the following options:

- Lowering the connection draining timeout with the risk of cancelling some in-flight requests that take longer than the timeout,
- Closing SSE connections after X minutes (where X < 15), so that the connection draining time will be limited to that time for SSE connections. The downside of this approach is that we're still waiting for max. X minutes, which means you would want to make X as low as possible, but by lowering X too much we are practically using long-polling instead of SSE.

As we find the above solutions lacking, we're looking for a way to *immediately* close all SSE connections whenever an instance is being removed from the load balancer, so that we don't have to wait for 15 minutes every time that happens.

For example, it would be ideal if the instance could subscribe to an event when it goes out-of-service. Unfortunately, so far we have not been able to find such a thing.

**Edit:** The challenge is in determining when the load balancer takes an instance out-of-service, so that we can then close the SSE connections from that instance.

**Edit 2:** We have solved the issue by looking at the incoming requests. As soon as the service detects no incoming requests for a certain amount of time (e.g. 60 seconds), it knows that there is a good chance it is being taken out-of-service, so it closes all SSE connections. Worst-case it is actually still in service, but as disconnected SSE clients will automatically reconnect, that doesn't matter much.

Comment: Send a message on the eventsource stream, telling the client to drop and reconnect?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The problem is that we don't know _when_ to drop the SSE connections, as that depends on when the load balancer takes the instance out-of-service.

Comment: Ah.  I assumed this was a deliberate scale-down.  So, send periodic keep-alive messages to the clients, which use a timer to detect that a connection has gone idle, and drop it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That does not really help, as the server keeps running during the connection drain period, which means it will keep sending keep-alives to the client even though it is being taken out-of-service.

Comment: The whole point of the connection draining phase is to allow the server to finish in-flight requests, while not sending any new requests to the server. As soon as all in-flight requests are finished, the instance can be terminated. However, open SSE connections (which are in fact HTTP requests of which the response stream is kept open indefinitely) will _never_ finish, resulting in the maximum waiting period for connection draining, which we set to 15 minutes in our case because of some other potentially long-running requests.